# Changing row data in SQLite table, without deleting and re-inserting updated values again

Tags: android, sqlite

I made SQLite database table that stores records, is it possible to change some values
that stored inside the table without deleting and entering updated values with older one.

e.g.
Lets say I want to change the wage of row ID = 0 to from 23$ to 40$ without deleting 
the first row and reinserting making the auto incremented ID change to 1,
is to possible?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, check out the [UPDATE syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) of SQLite.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should use an [`UPDATE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) statement.